# jQuery - html of <span> returning 'undefined'

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to increment the html value of a `<span>` when a button is clicked, but jQuery is saying that the value of the `<span>` is undefined, even though there is a number physically being shown on the page. Here is the PHP section that generates the HTML:

```
echo '<div class="box" style="background-color:'.$colours[0].'">
      <p>'.$confessions[0].'<br></p><br>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="slideleft">#'.$ids[0].'</div>
        <div class="slideright">
            <span class="upvote" id="'.$ids[0].'">Upvote</span>
            <span class="counter" id="'.$ids[0].'">"'.$counter[0].'"</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>'
```

and here is the jQuery that is supposed to magic up the HTML:

```
$("body").on("click", ".upvote", function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'vote.php',
        data: {
            type: 'up',
            id: $(this).attr('id')
        },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'ok') {
                alert($(this).next().html());
            } else {};
        }
    });
});
```

It does make an alert when the `upvote` button is pressed, but its value is `undefined` as opposed to the actual number. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(this)` won't contain the clicked element any more as it becomes out of scope whilst inside your success function, instead you will need to cache the variable for use inside your success function.

For example:

```
$("body").on("click", ".upvote", function(e){
    var clicked = $(this);
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'vote.php',
        data: { type: 'up', id: clicked.attr('id') },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 'ok'){
                alert(clicked.next().html());
            } else {
            };
        }
    });   
});
```

Comment: You can use the context option inside the ajax object. { url: ..., context: this}

Comment: It's also a good practice to prefix any `jQuery` objects with `$`. So `$clicked`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `this` is not what you expect; in the "success" callback, `this` has been rebound to the [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object- and getting its `next()` is what's returning undefined.

I recommend explicit capture to solve this problem:

```
$("body").on("click", ".upvote", function(e){
    var self = this; /// capture "this" explicitly here
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'vote.php',
        data: { type: 'up', id: $(this).attr('id') },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
                    if(data == 'ok'){
                    alert($(self).next().html()); /// so now it is available here
                  } else {
                  }
        }
    });   
});
```

Comment: Or use the context option to pass in `this`

Answer (score 1):

I think that `$(this)` isn't referencing your DOM element here. Before the ajax function try adding

```
var elem = $('.upvote');
```

And using

`elem` rather than `$(this)` in the ajax function.

Comment: or use the `context` option to pass in `this`

Comment: Oh, @Trevor this sounds like something I need to learn. Please can you edit my answer with that? - or provide your own and i'll up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

pass `this` as the `context` for it to applied in methods to `ajax`

No need to make a new var to access `this`

Check out the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
 $("body").on("click", ".upvote", function(e){

        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'vote.php',
            context: this, // capture this here instead
            data: { type: 'up', id: $(this).attr('id') },
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == 'ok'){
                    alert($(this).next().html()); /// so now it is available here
                } 
            }
        });   
    });
```